# How many maximal chains contain a and b

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I am currently trying to find how many maximal chains of a set S cardinality N contain subsets A, B where A is a subset of B with cardinality J and B is a subset of S with cardinality K.

I currently have that there are J!(K!(N-K)!-J)!, but after testing this out on a few sets I appear to be getting incorrect results.

I got this result by considering that the amount of maximal chains which of S which Contain B is K!(N-K)!. If M is a set which contains all maximal chains of S which contain B, then, I thought, since A is cardinality J and is a subset of B, then the amount of maximal chains of M which contain A must be J!(K!(N-K)!-J)!.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In order for us to tell you want you are doing wrong, you need to tell us your thought process which led to $J!(K!(N-K)!-J)!$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Assume that $J\subset K$. The maximal chain looks something like this:

$$
\newcommand{\s}{\hspace{.1cm}\underline{\hspace{.5cm}}\hspace{.1cm}}
\s \s \dots\s J \s\dots\s K\s\dots \s
$$

To count the number of maximal chains, you must answer three questions, and then multiply their answers together.

- How many ways are there to choose the portion of the chain up to $J$? Note that the elements of $J$ must be added one at a time in some arbitrary order, so there are $|J|!$ ways to choose this first part.
- How many ways are there to choose the portion of the chain between $J$ and $K$?
- How many ways are there to choose the portion of the chain after $K$?